# opening a file in administrator mode from excel VBA in windows 07

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel file which has a button in it.
if i click on the button,i should be able to open a file "myfile.exe" in an ADMINISTRATOR mode  which is in different location.

could someone please help me how this could be implemented using excel VBA in Windows07 machine...?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Can you please explain why the file has to be open in administrator mode? What is your goal here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it using `runas` but you need to have the password for it.

```
Shell "runas /profile /env /user:=<UserName>\admin ""c:\windows\Notepad.exe"""
```

**SNAPSHOTS**

Help on RunAs: type `runas/?` in DOS prompt to see the syntax.

[image]