# How to open file in Livelink using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, livelink

I am having a difficulties to find the way on how to open the file in LiveLink using VBA in Excel. I know the folder where its placed and I know the name of the file; is there any straightforward way to perform this please?

Many thanks in advance,

Michal

Comment: What kind of file?  You *should* be able to use the webdav path to open the file (assuming you mean you want to open an excel file in Excel...) Path will be something like  `WorkBook.Open "http://yourLLserver/livelinkdav/folder1/folder2/ExcelFileName.xls"`

Comment: I meant `WorkBooks.Open` of course...

Comment: Many thanks Tim, exactly what I was looking for! I couldn't figure out, how to specify the file/folder not based on the object number. It can be any kind of file, but I'd expect this should work in any case, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Shell function - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508724/opening-a-file-in-administrator-mode-from-excel-vba-in-windows-07) for more info. Also, see the VBA info on this function [here](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview.aspx?AssetId=HV805572399990&lcid=1033&NS=EXCEL%2EDEV&Version=12&respos=0&CTT=1&queryid=f1e2a625%2D06e1%2D4dc1%2D80e9%2D52b38ca3978a).

Comment: It doesn't seem you have any idea of what he was asking? Do you know Livelink and how to access object within?